# ze_zh / ze_en - What language is associated with these codes?

Tags: standards

This table lists many language codes for data sets, but I can't seem to find where the pair ze_zh or ze_en is defined:

[image]

None of the ISO code standards seem to list these pairs either.

Comment: This is probably an error, ask the source of the table for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this means that some of their data comes from a bilingual Chinese / English source. `zh` means Chinese and `en` means English, so it's reasonable that they invented `ze` to mean a bilingual data source including Chinese and English.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you got this table from the Open Subtitles Corpus?
http://opus.nlpl.eu/OpenSubtitles-v2018.php

That points to the paper "OpenSubtitles2016: Extracting Large Parallel Corpora from Movie and TV Subtitles" by Lison and Tiedemman published at LREC 2016.
http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2016/pdf/947_Paper.pdf

The paper doesn't use language codes, but it has this quote:

> The dataset also includes bilingual Chinese-English subtitles, which are subtitles displaying two languages at once, one per line (Zhang et al., 2014). These bilingual subtitles are split in their two constituent languages during the conversion.

I don't know why they don't just label these as `en` and `zh`, but once you look into it more, I'm sure it will make sense.

Comment: Thanks. That looks to be exactly what the codes designate.

Comment: Brendan, If you figure out more about how they work, feel free to improve this answer.